# Error: indexing array 'channels'

Tags: model-checking, spin, promela

I get this error with `Spin 6.4.8`:

```
spin: indexing channels[-1] - size is 3
spin: 2.pml:13, Error: indexing array 'channels'
```

when running a simulation of the following *Promela Model*:

```
chan channels[3] = [1] of { pid };

active [3] proctype node () {
    short pred = (_pid - 1) % 3;
    short succ = (_pid + 1) % 3;
    printf("Values(%d): %d, %d\n", _pid, pred, succ);
    if
        :: pred == -1 -> pred = 2;
        :: else -> skip;
    fi;
    printf("Corrected Values(%d): %d, %d\n", _pid, pred, succ);
    {
        chan pc = channels[pred];
        chan sc = channels[succ];
    }
}
```

As witnessed by the following output trace, I do **not** access the offending `-1` array location as claimed by the error message:

```
  Values(0): -1, 1
          Values(2): 1, 0
      Values(1): 0, 2
      Corrected Values(1): 0, 2
          Corrected Values(2): 1, 0
  Corrected Values(0): 2, 1
```

After further analysis, which is not shown here, it also looks like that `pc` and `sc` are always initialized to the right channel value when I try to access them.

**Q:** why do I get an error message, and how do I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE**: the code proposed in the question will no longer produce any error starting from `Spin` version `6.4.9` onward, thanks to updates.

---

Here is the solution:

> Variables that apper anywhere in a proctype body are instantiated when
>   the process is created. [...] To avoid this kind of thing it's better
>   to separate declaration from initialization.
>
> *[G. H., private communication]*

For some reasons, if a variable is both declared and initialized in the same statement, when `Spin 6.4.8` instantiates them at process creation it also attempts to perform the same kind of initialization specified in the *Promela Model*.

On the given example, the `node` with `_pid` equal to `0` has `pred` equal to `-1` at creation time, so `Spin`'s attempt to also execute `chan pc = channels[pred];` leads to an error because there is an out-of-bounds access.

As suggested above, one can fix this issue by separating declaration from initialization:

```
chan channels[3] = [1] of { pid };

active [3] proctype node () {
    short pred = (_pid - 1) % 3;
    short succ = (_pid + 1) % 3;
    printf("Values(%d): %d, %d\n", _pid, pred, succ);
    if
        :: pred == -1 -> pred = 2;
        :: else -> skip;
    fi;
    printf("Corrected Values(%d): %d, %d\n", _pid, pred, succ);
    {
        chan pc;
        chan sc;
        pc = channels[pred];
        sc = channels[succ];
    }
}
```

has the following output:

```
~$ spin test.pml 
              Values(2): 1, 0
      Values(0): -1, 1
          Values(1): 0, 2
          Corrected Values(1): 0, 2
              Corrected Values(2): 1, 0
      Corrected Values(0): 2, 1
3 processes created
```

---

Alternatively, one can circumvent the problem and prevent `pred` from ever having an invalid value:

```
chan channels[3] = [1] of { pid };

active [3] proctype node () {
    short pred = (_pid - 1 + 3) % 3;
    short succ = (_pid + 1) % 3;
    printf("Values(%d): %d, %d\n", _pid, pred, succ);
    {
        chan pc = channels[pred];
        chan sc = channels[succ];
    }
}
```